# Hangfire Dashboard page displaying 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

Looking for some help in setting up HangFire Dashboard in Visual Studio for Mac." I have created a DotNet Framework WebAPI project.

I have referenced Hangfire.SqlServer, Hangfire, and Hangfire.dashboard packages in my project. During startup, HangFire is initialized with the below code.

```
public void ConfigureHangfire(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage("ConnectionString", new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true


            }).UseConsole();



        JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("ConnectionString");
        app.UseHangfireServer();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions()
        {

            Authorization = new[] { new AuthenticatedAuthorizationFiler() }


        }, JobStorage.Current);

//Called to simulate a test job run
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Debug.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"));


    }
```

I have decorated my startup class with:
[assembly:OwinStartup(typeof(Project.App_Start.Startup))]

When I navigate to my **/jobs** URL, I am getting a 404 page not found. I have also tried. I have Microsoft.Owin referenced and it is in my bin folder.

I have set

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have followed the documentation provided here: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-applications.html to write my startup code. I am not too sure why I am not able to reach a dashboard page for hangfire.

Any help in pinpointing my issue here would be greatly appreciated!